# Is is possible to upload the native iOS app on website send user link to download and install

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

I have app which i do not want to submit to appstore but i want that user to whom i may provide the link for the app can download and install the features.I saw same app from client which gives us url when we open it asks for download and install the app on ipad or iphone so any idea or way so that we can upload the native iOS app to url and download and install from that i searched some say the use adhoc distribution but by this you need to send profile and then install using itunes but i want from url to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be part of the iOS enterprise program (generally speaking). Additionally testflight (www.testflightapp.com) will work for regular non enterprise memberships to the developer program.

Comment: if i become iOS enterprise program member then i can distribute app like this using url or not

Comment: @user2240329 You cannot, it is a violation of the terms of the agreement.  You may only distribute it to your employees and contractors.  Furthermore, you need to be a registered business in order to join the program.

Comment: yes i want to distribute this to contractors so how will i distribute this app like we use in adhoc distribution getting UDID of all devices and send them provisioning

Comment: You do not need UDID for enterprise, they need to have the profile installer for enterprise membership however.

Comment: Do you mean a beta tester of your app, or testing beta versions of iOS ?(which is allowed for developer members). You may send multiple versions of your app out, it does not matter for enterprise distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You need signature to download and install an app, so you can't just ask people to download your app (unless you put the entire xcode project on the web). But you can consider to use Testflight to distribute app for demo. Check out [Testflight](http://www.testflightapp.com/)

Comment: It mean no any way to do this without using entire xcode project on web.

Comment: You need to add your user's device key to your signature file, compile the whole thing with the signature file, so user can execute the compiled file they downloaded from the URL. But the process is very long and time consuming. So trust me, Testflight is your best option, it automates a lot of these processes.

Comment: by testfligh i have to also add the UDID of all the devices can you pleas share me any resource for which you told that is long process